# How to sort numbers in Python without using built-in methods

Tags: sorting, numbers

I am trying to sort 3 numbers in python, without using the built-in sort methods such as 'sorted' or .sort.

Say I have the numbers...

**2, 500, 25, 15, 12**

I want to output as **2, 12, 15, 25, 500**

I want to mimic how to sorted function built into python works, but can't find the source for it.

For 3 numbers I did:

```
msg = "Give me a number: "
pfix = " is the greatest"


a = int(input(msg))
b = int(input(msg))
c = int(input(msg))
nums = []

if a>b and a>c:
    nums.append(a)
elif b>a and b>c:
    nums.append(b)
else:
    nums.append(c)


if a>b and b>c:
    nums.append(b)
elif a>b and b>c:
    nums.append(b)
elif a>c and c>b:
    nums.append(c)
elif b>a and a>c:
    nums.append(a)
elif b>c and c>a:
    nums.append(c)
elif c>a and a>b:
    nums.append(a)
elif c>b and b>a:
    nums.append(b)

if a<b and a<c:
    nums.append(a)
elif b<a and b<c:
    nums.append(b)
elif c<b and c<a:
    nums.append(c)

print(nums)
```

I know this is a bad way as it will only work for 3 numbers. I need something that work for a indefinite list of numbers using a for loop

Like...

```
def num_sort(_list):
    for i in range(0, len(_list)):
    ...
```

And use like this

```
print(num_sort([2, 500, 25, 15, 12]))
```

And how would I go about getting particular sort?
e.g Ascending or Descending...

I know it like reinventing the wheel but I was told I need to make my own method.

What would you do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read up on sorting methods: bubble, insertion, merge, quick

Comment: Not to be rude but, if you were asked to make your own method, why are you asking us? Do you know of any sorting algorithms?

Comment: I handed in the code above and they chose to accept because no matter how terrible it is it does what they asked. 3 numbers. i would like to know the way it should be done upon reflection.

Answer (score 0):

quickSort Algo - http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort

```
def sort(array):
    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []

    if len(array) > 1:
        pivot = array[0]
        for x in array:
            if x < pivot:
                less.append(x)
            if x == pivot:
                equal.append(x)
            if x > pivot:
                greater.append(x)
        return sort(less)+equal+sort(greater)  
    else: 
        return array
print(sort([12,4,5,6,7,3,1,15]))
```